# A formula of the major garbage collection threshold

Tags: programming-languages, compilers, garbage-collection

I'm studying the garbage collection code of Alex Aiken's [COOL](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eaiken/software/cool/cool-manual.pdf) programming language's [runtime system](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eaiken/software/cooldist/lib/trap.handler).

(This is the language used in a relatively famous [Stanford Online Compilers course](https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+2T2020/home))

A major garbage collection is triggered according to a formula described in the runtime system's code:

```
#     breakpoint: Point where a major collection will occur.  It is
#         calculated by the following formula:
#
#         breakpoint = MIN(L3-MAX(MAJOR0,MAJOR1)-MAX(MINOR0,MINOR1),
#                          L3-(L3-L0)/2)
#
#         where (variables stored in the header):
#           MAJOR0 = total size of objects in the new area after last major
#                    collection.
#           MAJOR1 = (MAJOR0+MAJOR1)/2
#           MINOR0 = total size of objects in the reserve area after last
#                    minor collection.
#           MINOR1 = (MINOR0+MINOR1)/2
```

Could someone please describe the reasoning this formula is based on or point me to documentation explaining it.